# SQL BigQuery: Исключение одной таблицы из другой

Tags: sql

**Ситуация:**
Пытаюсь получить список id пользователей, которые не прошли на следующий шаг воронки.
Чтобы использовать в дальнейшем этот список как сегмент и при других запросах брать пользователей из этого списка.

Я сделал запрос воронкой и получил следующие значения
*шаг 1* → 3239,
*шаг 2* → 2758

Код запроса

```
WITH 

Pages AS (
 SELECT 
 device.category as device,
   event_name, 
   user_pseudo_id, 
   event_timestamp,
   (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = "page_location" ) as pagePath
  FROM `analytics_15254172.events_*`
  WHERE event_name IN (SELECT event_name FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE value.string_value LIKE "%ru.hostname.com/ru/%") 
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATETIME(TIMESTAMP "2022-06-15 00:00:00+00", "Asia/Krasnoyarsk")) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATETIME(TIMESTAMP "2022-06-16 00:00:00+00", "Asia/Krasnoyarsk"))
)

---- FunnelTable

SELECT step2_id    
FROM (
    SELECT
      user_pseudo_id AS step1_id,
      event_timestamp AS step1_timestamp,
      step2_id,
      step2_timestamp
    FROM
      Pages
      LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT
         user_pseudo_id AS step2_id,
         event_timestamp AS step2_timestamp
       FROM 
         Pages
       WHERE 
         pagePath = "СТРАНИЦА 2"
      )
     ON
       user_pseudo_id = step2_id
       AND event_timestamp < step2_timestamp
       
    WHERE
    pagePath = "СТРАНИЦА 1"
)
```

**Проблема:**
После того, как получил список id, что перешли на второй шаг
Я попытался взять id пользователей, у которых стоит значение NULL после присоединения через LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT step1_id) FROM FunnelTable
WHERE step2_id IS NULL
```

Но результат подсчета id пользователей по тем, кто не перешел на второй шаг выдает значение 676 пользователей. В то время как *шаг 1* (3239) - *шаг 2* (2758) = 481 пользователь. Т.е. значения не бьются

Затем я попробовал взять из основной таблицы Pages только тех, кто был на шаге 1 и его ID не входит в список ID пользователей на шаге 2.

```
SELECT user_pseudo_id FROM Pages
WHERE user_pseudo_id NOT IN (SELECT step2_id FROM FunnelTable) 
AND pagePath = "СТРАНИЦА 1"
```

Но результат выдает 0, словно нет соответствия id пользователей.

Не понимаю, что не так
И как мне получить список id пользователей, которые не переходили на следующий шаг воронки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение вопроса
Выборка тех, кто был на шаге 1, но не перешел на шаг 2

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT step1_id) FROM Funnel_table AS a WHERE a.step1_id NOT IN
 (SELECT a.step1_id FROM Funnel_table AS b WHERE a.step1_id = b.step2_id)
```